# problem with alias being interpreted in command arguments

Tags: bash, alias

I have the following alias:

```
alias mv='mv -i'
alias git='LANG=en_US \git '
```

then when I do a `git mv` command the `mv` is interpreted as `mv -i`:

```
$ git mv a b
error: unknown switch `i'
```

I would like the alias to apply only if it is a bash command

Versions:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)
- git version 2.7.4   (also I don't think it's linked to git)

Notes:

- `git \mv a b` works
- unaliasing git also works `\git mv a b`

Comment: I can't really reproduce this with Git 2.12.4 and Bash 4.4.12.

Comment: In `bash` *v4.4*, aliases only work if the alias is the first word on a line. 
Demo: `alias woo="woo hoo" ; echo woo` outputs `woo`.

Comment: I would call this alias `mvi` or something similar.

Comment: Are you sure? A workaround could be to make `mv` a bash *function* (not an alias).

Comment: I've got the same versions installed here, and I can't reproduce that either. Must be something special with your bash configuration; you could check the aliases and environment for something `git` related. What do you get when trying `type -a mv` and `type -a git`?

Comment: @Murphy 
 
# type -a mv

mv is an alias to « mv -i »

mv is /bin/mv

# type -a git

git is an alias to « LANG=en_US \git  »

git is /usr/bin/git

Comment: unaliasing git also works "\git mv a b"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `git` is an alias **ending with a space**, bash performs alias expansion on the word immediately after it:

```
$ alias mv='mv -i'
$ alias git=': git '
$ set -x
$ git mv
+ : git mv -i
```

From [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases):

> If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next
>   command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Make `git` an alias without the space:

```
alias git='LANG=en_US git'
```

Note that:

> The first word of the replacement text is tested for aliases, but a
>   word that is identical to an alias being expanded is not expanded a
>   second time. This means that one may alias `ls` to `ls -F`, for
>   instance, and Bash does not try to recursively expand the replacement
>   text.

So, you don't need `\git` there.

Comment: You are right, removing this extra space did the job, thanks !